# What do '>' and '&' mean in less.js?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I am going through bootstrap's less code. I am curious what do '>' and '&' mean in defining css class?

```
  .navbar-nav {                                                                           
    > li > a {                                                                            
      color: @navbar-custom-link-color;                                                   

      &:hover,                                                                            
      &:focus {                                                                           
        color: @navbar-custom-link-hover-color;                                           
      }                                                                                   
    }                                                                                     
    > .active > a {                                                                       
      &,                                                                                  
      &:hover,                                                                            
      &:focus {                                                                           
        color: @navbar-custom-link-active-color;                                          
      }                                                                                   
    }                                                                                     
    > .disabled > a {                                                                     
      &,                                                                                  
      &:hover,                                                                            
      &:focus {                                                                           
        color: @navbar-default-link-disabled-color;                                       
        background-color: @navbar-default-link-disabled-bg;                               
      }                                                                                   
    }                                                                                     
  }
```

Is there any detailed tutorial for less.js that I can refer?

Comment: `>` has the same meaning as in pure CSS (child selector). `&` is the [parent selector](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature). Asking for recommendation on tutorials is considered off-topic here but the official Less website has a good explanation of the features.

Comment: "Is there any detailed tutorial for less.js that I can refer?" Uhm, *yes*. Try searching (the less documentation will provide additional resources to explore, mainly it being derived from CSS).

Comment: I don't know why it is so hard to just copy paste the documentation links here instead of being mean to the OP. 

For future reference, here - 
[LESS Github](https://github.com/less/less-docs/blob/master/content/features/parent-selectors.md)
[LESS Docs](https://lesscss.org/features/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Greater Than

As Harry mentioned, the greater than `>` sytax is the same as in regular CSS, namely that the 2nd listed element is a child of the first element.

See the table under `Selectors based on relationships` on [**this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) URL:

`A > E:     Any E element that is a child of an A element`

### Ampersand

The ampersand is a shortcut to reference the current parent selector, so in your first example, the pure css would end up looking like this:

```
  navbar-nav:hover,                                                                            
  navbar-nav:focus {                                                                           
    color: @navbar-custom-link-hover-color;                                           
  }
```

[**Here**](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand) is a good article explaining the use of the ampersand character in LESS/SASS

### Tutorial

While not exactly tutorial, here is the [**complete Language reference for LESS**](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature) (linked to the section about referencing parent selectors with `&`)

Answer (score 3):

`>` means the same thing that it does in regular CSS - it targets only direct children of the parent element.

`&` means that the selector is added onto the parent selector.  For example:

### LESS

```
.header {
  &:first-child {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

### Pure CSS Equivalent

```
.header:first-child {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```